# Where & How to add counter and use it to increment innerText of appended list items - DOM

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dom

Using DOM - The button will append items to a list when clicked, but it also needs to increment the innerText integer [i] of each appended list item. I don't know how to make it increment.

I've tried adding a counter inside function insertItem(), and also inside button.addEventListener without success. Example of counter:

```
let clickCount = 0;
clickCount++:
```

#### HTML

```
<body>
    <button class='button'>Click to add new list item</button>

</body>
```

#### JavaScript

```
let button = document.querySelector('button');
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.className = 'button';

    button.addEventListener('click', insertItem);
    
    function insertItem() {
        let list = document.createElement('ul');
 
        document.body.appendChild(list);
    
        for (let i = 1; i === 1; i++) {
            let item = document.createElement('li');
            let text = document.createTextNode('This is list item ' + [i]);
                item.appendChild(text);
                list.appendChild(item);
        
                document.getElementsByName('item').innerHTML = 'This is list item ' + [i+1];
        }
    }
```

I want innerText ('This is list item ' + [i]) to increment by 1 with each button click.

As of now, my code functions but the [i] doesn't increment; it remains as '1' with every click/append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Your button is already part of your HTML - there is no need to append it again at the start.
2. You use a for loop, but it doesn't loop and instead only runs your code once (thus, there is no need for it)
3. You are creating multiple unordered lists (`ul` tags), when you can instead create one outside of your function, and add items (`li` tags) into that `ul` tag.

Once you have resolved these issues, you can create a global variable called `clickCounter` and use that as the number at the end of each of your items. Each time you add an item to your list you can increment `clickCounter` using `clickCounter++`. I have made `clickCounter` global as if it was inside your function it will reset every time your button is clicked which is not what you want.

See working example below:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button.button'); // get the button element with the button class

button.addEventListener('click', insertItem);

let clickCounter = 1;
let list = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(list);

function insertItem() {
  let item = document.createElement('li');
  let text = document.createTextNode('This is list item ' + clickCounter);
  item.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(item);
  clickCounter++;
}
```

```html
<button class='button'>Click to add new list item</button>
```